# What are the security implications (if any) of allowing any password?

Tags: security, passwords

As [Ars](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/04/why-your-password-cant-have-symbols-or-be-longer-than-16-characters/) and many others have pointed out, even large organizations with extensive, presumably intelligent IT departments employ rules for password creation that are not always in the best interest of security.

Sometimes though, it is still hard to understand why some applications restrict certain characters but allow others, and why other applications have rules that contrast all other applications. All of this makes me feel like I am missing something.

I have been taught to never trust raw input from a user, so it feels wrong to allow input from the user and not validate it, however I am conflicted. In this case I feel there is a strong argument for allowing the user to enter anything, and not validate it (because there would be no need).

For illustrative reasons, take the following hypothetical user registration system:

### A Hypothetical User Registration System

1. A user navigates to a form for registering an account with a website.
2. Among other inputs, the user is prompted for a password. The user is told they may enter any desired password. There are no rules. It can be absolutely any string of characters.
3. Upon receiving the submitted form (or any request, legitimate or malicious), the server does not validate the password field: it simply hashes whatever was given.
4. The hash is stored in a database for use later.

for instance, in PHP:

```
password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

**If there are any, what are the security implications of this system?**

Is there any kind of specially-crafted request that someone can possible submit that would cause unintended consequences in this system? If so, please provide examples.

Would some server-side languages be susceptible to attacks from this, but others not? Which ones?

Again, this system is illustrative. Please do not argue what merits or downfalls a system like this may have in terms of the security of its users' passwords themselves, only what security implications it may have on the system itself.

Comment: "it simply hashes whatever was given" [it's not hard to come up with a reason why that is going to end bad](https://3v4l.org/n3BoW)... Also the function expects at least two params..

Comment: @PeeHaa It is hard for me. Please explain :). You are correct, I fixed the code example.

Comment: @PeeHaa, I am guessing you mean that it is a problem because a user can choose, per your example, an empty string as their password. Again, I am only asking about the security implications this system would impose on a server, not how secure it is for its users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common reason for preventing certain characters is that the developers don't know how to correctly handle passwords in whatever language they are working in, and rather than learn to do so, they try to limit what data they accept (often incorrectly). Alternately, they rely on third party components that handle passwords incorrectly and believe that they are powerless to fix this. (This is described in the article you link.)

If the code is precisely as you describe, with no fancy JavaScript in the middle touching the input, no middleware unpacking data structures, no logging systems writing passwords, no writing raw passwords into the database, no SQL queries built up as strings that might include the password, no unhashed passwords in the database, no incorrectly encoded strings in URLs, etc., then yeah, it's great. It's almost perfect (I'd much rather you apply some hashing before posting to the server, but there are some arguments there either way).

In modern applications, developers slap together all of the things mentioned in the last paragraph, and then apply a layer of hope and prayer and then scramble to patch when someone publishes an exploit. Everything in the last paragraph is horrible, and common.

So if you see restrictions on what characters are acceptable, it means the password handling system was either built poorly or the developers don't trust it. That is common, so restrictions are common.